# Get page that displays all children of taxonomy parent

Tags: php, functions, categories

I created a Taxonomy called `articleTopics`. The taxonomy has two parent terms, and the same six children terms for each. I have to link to a page which shows all children of either parent term.

For clarification: 
navigating to bla.com/articletopics/testchild works.
navigating to bla.com/articletopics only renders index.php (neither page-articletopics, nor taxonomy-articletopics, nor archive-articletopics seems to work).

Of course I could create a page template and assign it to a page that I can render to achieve this. But before I do, I wanted to find out if there is a Wordpress-native way to do this, or whether I am appproaching this incorrectly.